# HTML Image Outside Of Border

Tags: html, css, border

I am making myself a homepage for my browser, and I'm trying to put 3 images with captions evenly spaced in a divider. It seems to work but the border for the outmost divider does not cover the images. What do I do? Here is the code.

```css
/* Body: */
body {
 background-color: #CCCCCC;
}
/* Title: */
#title {
 color: #00FFFD;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 1000%;
}
/* Main Border: */
#outer_div {
 width: 100%;
}

#inner_div {
 width: 80%;
 margin: auto;
 border: 10px groove #000;
}

#main {
 border: 40px solid transparent;
}
/* Link Dividers */
.link {
 width: 33%;
 float: left;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <title>Hub</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/hub.css" />
</head>
<body>
 <div id="title"><u>Website Hub</u></div>
 <div id="outer_div">
  <div id="inner_div">
   <div id="main">
    <div id="row1">
     <div class="link">
      <a><img src="img/one.png" border="2px"></a>
      <caption>One</caption>
     </div>
     <div class="link">
      <a><img src="img/two.jpg" border="2px"></a>
      <caption>Two</caption>
     </div>
     <div class="link">
      <a><img src="img/three.jpg" border="2px"></a>
      <caption>Three</caption>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try giving dimensions to the img?

.link img {

 width: 100%;
}

Answer (score 0):

You could always put the border declaration in the CSS instead...

```
.link {
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid #1f1f1f;
}
```

Or extend the declaration:

```
.link a img { border: 2px solid #1f1f1f; }
.link a { width: 100%; } // Will be inherited by the child element...
```